# Python New to this instead of while, I wanna use a for loop

Tags: python

```
I = 19
while I != 35:
    I +=1
    print (I)
```

I want to make this a for loop not a while loop for python I have tried:

```
for (int I = 21; I <= 35; I += 1):
print (I)
```

but that does not work any suggestions

Comment: Can you try `for I in range(21,36):`

Comment: It didn't work because it's not Python syntax.

Comment: @Aria West, check the answers, they should work. You can accept one of them, if it worked for you, otherwise you can edit your answer to make us understand what explaination is missing.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested above you can use the Python iterable class `range`, of which `__init__` method can take two arguments (the beginning and the end of the range).

```
for i in range(21, 36): # If you want it to stop after 35 you have to specify 36 as the end
    print(i)
```

---

Actually you wrote a `for` loop in `C`/`C++` style, in Python we don't have a pure for loop, but we have a `foreach` loop (written with keyword `for` anyway) that can be used as a pure for loop when iterating over a `range` object.

This syntax:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++): // C++
    ...
```

Becomes:

```
for i in range(10): # Python
    ...
```

That's like equivalent to:

```
for i in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]:
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Your while loop will print numbers from 20 to 35 inclusively.

```
I = 19
while I != 35:
    I +=1              # will print the next I (so starting at 20)
    print (I)
```

The equivalent for-loop in Python would use a range that starts at 20 and stops once it reaches 36:

```
for I in range(20,36):
    print(I)
```